# Tycho build error: "... requires bundle ... but it could not be found"

Tags: eclipse, plugins, eclipse-rcp, tycho

We have an eclipse Luna plugin application which we're trying to build with Tycho.  When we try to do a `mvn clean verify`, we're getting this type of message:

```
[ERROR]  Cannot resolve project dependencies:
[ERROR]   Software being installed: our.app 1.0.0.qualifier
[ERROR]   Missing requirement: our.app 1.0.0.qualifier requires 'bundle org.eclipse.core.runtime 3.7.0' but it could not be found
```

When we look at the logs it appears that any Eclipse plugin that is required will give us this error, and that this is merely the first item in the list on the MANIFEST.MF for the plugin being verified.

I have looked at other questions, but none of them seem to address this particular issue.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

MANIFEST.MF:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: Our App
Bundle-SymbolicName: our.app;singleton:=true
Built-By: Our Team (2014)
Bundle-ClassPath: .,
 <some jars>
Bundle-Vendor: Our Team
Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.core.runtime;bundle-version="3.7.0",
 org.eclipse.ui;bundle-version="3.7.0",
 org.eclipse.ui.ide;bundle-version="3.7.0",
 org.eclipse.core.resources;bundle-version="3.7.0",
 org.eclipse.ui.forms;bundle-version="3.6.0",
 org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui;bundle-version="1.3.0",
 org.eclipse.jface.text;bundle-version="3.8.100",
 org.eclipse.ui.workbench.texteditor;bundle-version="3.8.101",
 org.eclipse.ui.views;bundle-version="3.6.0"
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.6
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0.qualifier
```

Comment: When I add dependencies, I go to the plugin.xml in my project, click the dependencies tab, add, and then add the required dependency.

Comment: The next line of the error message is `[ERROR] See http://wiki.eclipse.org/Tycho/Dependency_Resolution_Troubleshooting for help.` Did you look at [that page](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Tycho/Dependency_Resolution_Troubleshooting)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I get a similar error if I remove the `<repository>`-tag from the pom.
Without that information Tycho does not know where to download the required packages.
Therefore you have to add the following snippet to your pom:

```
<repository>
   <id>eclipse-indigo</id>
   <url>http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo</url>
   <layout>p2</layout>
</repository>
```

I copied the snippet from [here](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Tycho/Target_Platform), for more information look [here](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Scout/Tutorial/4.0/Maven_Tycho_Build).

Comment: I had a similar error, as Tycho doesn't find my plugins, and i resolved this by adding the local repository. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Tycho reads your MANIFEST.MF and feature.xml to find the dependencies of your plugins and adds them (temporarily) to your POMs which are used by Maven to perform the build. The idea of Tycho is to maintain the dependencies solely in the MANIFEST.MF and feature.xml, freeing you from the need to add them to the POMs, too. However, you still need to add an appropriate repository, usually in the parent POM, in which the dependent plugins can be found. This is obviously missing in your POMs.

Comment: Thank you!  This is correct, and worked.  I tried to mark both answers correct but it's not letting mark your answer.