# Tycho build error: “… requires bundle … but it could not be found”

Tags: eclipse, maven, eclipse-rcp, m2e, tycho

I'm trying to build an RCP application using Tycho/m2e but I am facing this problem :

Missing requirement: MyApp 1.0.0.qualifier requires 'bundle org.eclipse.ui 3.108.1' but it could not be found.

org.eclipse.ui 3.108.1 is part of my neon installation...

Here is my configuration or what I have already tried to do without success :

1) I have neon repository in main pom :

```
<repository>
    <id>Neon</id>
    <layout>p2</layout>
    <url>http://download.eclipse.org/releases/neon/</url>
</repository>
```

2) Rebuild neon project repository index from Maven repo View within Eclipse (I cannot browse it !)

3) Restart Eclipse with "Download repository index updates on startup" checked in Maven preferences

I have seen this similar question :
[Tycho build error: "... requires bundle ... but it could not be found"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30629469/tycho-build-error-requires-bundle-but-it-could-not-be-found) but not found any solution.

What am I doing wrong ?

Thanks a lot for your help,
Frank

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the repository at http://download.eclipse.org/releases/neon/ indeed does **not** contain `org.eclipse.ui` in version `3.108.1`; it only contains version `3.108.0`.

To verify this, I recommend the *Repository Explorer (Oomph)* view. Switch to *Expert Mode* (the `C` icon in the view’s toolbar) and copy & paste the update site URL. Then search for `org.eclipse.ui` and you will see that the latest version available is `3.108.0.v20160518-1929`.

FYI, your options 2 and 3 won’t help with Tycho-related problems. The *Maven Repositories* view of m2e is for Maven repositories only, not p2 repositories. Also, the *repository indexes* mentioned by m2e are indexes of Maven repositories, not p2 repositories.

Comment: Thank you Andreas. I have tried to get Repository Explorer (Oomph) but only found Oomph installer... And sorry I am mixing maven indexes and p2 repositories. What is the solution to this problem ? Another repository URL ? Change plugin min version in dependencies ?

Comment: For Repository Explorer, must install "Oomph Setup SDK". I can now check for plugins versions, thanks :-). I've changed plugin min version in dependencies to 3.108.0 and build is now ok.

Comment: Instead of changing plugin min version, I've finally preferred to change maven neon repository to : http://download.eclipse.org/staging/neon.

Comment: Just be aware that the `staging/neon` repository is a moving target as we are currently heading for Neon.2, the second service release of Eclipse Neon. That being said, do you really need *that* fine-grained control over your dependencies’ versions? Wouldn’t a version range of `[3.108.0,4)` be sufficient?

Comment: Thanks for the advice, you are right. I go back to the first solution using the range you suggest.